Searching multiple intexes in cognitive search
So I have a hundred or so inedexes with different information from various sources. all the data is embeded using adda2.
Now I'm trying to iterate over the list of indexes and query each:
index_client = SearchIndexClient(
    endpoint=pierre_itfunds_endpoint, credential=pierre_itfunds_credential
)
index_client.list_indexes()
rows_list = []
for index in indexes:
    search_client = SearchClient(search_service_endpoint, index, credential)  
    vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=search_vector, k_nearest_neighbors=3, fields="content_vector")
    results = search_client.search(  
        search_text=query,  
        vector_queries= [vector_query], 
        select=["title", "text"],
        top=3
    )
    for row in results:
        dict1 = {}
        dict1.update({'index':index, 'score':row['@search.score'], 'title':row['title'], 'text':row['text']}) 
        rows_list.append(dict1)
res = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)

then I get the average score for each index:
grouped = res.groupby('index')['score'].agg(['mean'])
grouped

However the resulting avg score doesnt seem consistent:



index_name
avg_score




worng-idx
8.3763725667


other1-idx
4.5701991333


other2-idx
4.2485168


other3-idx
3.5756512667


CORRECT-idx
2.5451367667


...
...



I had hopped that using the same embbedder for all the content the cosine distance would be consistent across inedexes... which says nothing about the score, but still.
Is there a way to do this search, or normalize the scores so the highest has the most relevant answers?

Instead of doing average on top 3 documents you take only highest score that is top 1 document, then compare it with other indexes score without groupby.

did the experiment. that one wrong index consistently returns high scores. even though the documents it finds arent even that related.

please add sample of 1-3 index and your vector query, search text. In index the relevant index are scored correctly. so add you sample data.
